# Liferay 7 and Alfresco Atom CMIS Repository integration with SSO

Tags: alfresco, liferay-7

My Requirement is to integrate Liferay 7 with Alfresco 5.2, using the Documents and Media portlet through Atom pub URL.

I am able to connect the ALfresco repository when the user log's in into Liferay from the Liferay login screen.

But when the NTLM authentication is enable in Liferay then I am not able to connect to Alfresco.

I have set the property session.store.password=true in portal-ext.properties.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integration using a session stored password. When the user is logging in the portal over the login portlet it stores the plain text password into the session and then uses this information to access the Alfresco server.

You are skipping this step with NTLM. TO make the OOTB integration work you would need to populate the session with the required data but you can't do that as you don't have the plaintext password.

What is your use case? A possible hack/solution will depend on it.

Comment: Thanks Miroslav for the reply, My use case is that the user will be logged in into the Liferay portal through NTLM. Once the user is in the portal, he should be able to search and access the Alfresco documents based on the permission defined in Alfresco.

Comment: OOTB you will not achieve this. If you are able to modify the alfresco side then you might address it via some tokens that would be passed instead of the user credentials. You could probably also try to pass the NTLM headers if alfresco also supports login over NTLM. The last option would be to create a custom portlet that would present the files but you still need to resolve the logging on alfresco